# Code Injection to set and extract data from MFC Application

Tags: c#, c++, dll, mfc, code-injection

For my class project, I have to inject code into a simple randomly assigned app with a couple buttons and labels. After some research, I was able to identify the app as a C++ MFC app (still not 100% sure).

I was taught how to inject a C# dll into a .Net app to get and set data. However, I don't know if its applicable for a MFC app. I was able to inject a C# dll into the MFC app and even launch a messagebox. I don't know C++ well enough to get/set data.

Can I get/set data within a C++ MFC app using C# or do I have inject C++ dll into the MFC app and somehow use it to get/set couple buttons & labels?

---

Update 1: I realize I may be incorrect on my C++ assumptions. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703669/exe-programming-language-identity).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a strange class project but yes you can injection your own dlls into other process's using winapi from c# using pinvoke.

The main methods you would use to dll inject are OpenProcess, WriteProcessMemory, CreateRemoteThreadEx, VirtualAllocEx, GetProcAddress.

PInvoke them like below:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
```

See [How to inject a dll into a remote process c#](http://www.codingvision.net/miscellaneous/c-inject-a-dll-into-a-process-w--createremotethread)

See [How to inject a managed assembly DLL](http://web.archive.org/web/20101224064236/http://codingthewheel.com/archives/how-to-inject-a-managed-assembly-dll)

Comment: I already know how to inject a C# dll into a MFC app. How would I call any MFC GUI properties from within the app? In a .Net app, I would call via Applications.OpenForm or Applications.Current.Windows. I have no clue about c++.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what do you mean by "GUI Properties'. MFC is built around Win32 API. This operates on parameters that take HWND, a window handle. For example, to set the text of a static control, you would call the SerWindowText API or PostMessage(hand, WM_TEXT, ...).

Comment: @DavidChing In C#, GUI properties like Textbox.Text. When I first learned C++, they never taught GUI anything, just console. Is there a static handle that I can poll with my injected DLL?