# Exe programming language identity

Tags: c#, c++, .net

To continue my class [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660057/code-injection-to-set-and-extract-data-from-mfc-application), I need to identify the programming language of a sample exe. The following is what I know about the exe:

1. Uses x86 .Net 4.0 framework - It references mscorlib via JetBrains [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) program.
2. Has a Win32 gui with win32 buttons and labels - According to the   framework id on [UI Verify](https://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/releases/view/11366) (still using the old version). I tested UI Verify framework id against a WPF and WinForm sample exe.

At first I assumed its a C++ / CLI project but I also discovered a reference to System.Windows.Forms and methods that would decompile to C#.

What programming language is this exe written with?

---

Update 1: Using ILSpy, I discovered exe was "mixed + native code" as per @xanatos advice. I also noticed it references Microsoft.VisualC .

---

Update 2: As for my reference and for others who may need help in identifying a .net referenced exe, I did the following:

1. Verify exe referenced .Net (.mscorlib) via JetBrains or ILSpy
2. Checked the GUI and its controls to help identify the framework id
   via UI Verify
3. Check the `.corflags` to identify if it is ILOnly or mixed via
   ILSpy's IL view
4. Identify the exe's entry point via ILSpy (I had to change it to C#
   View and selected the exe)
5. Check if entry point method had `hidebysig` via ILSpy (I clicked the
   entry point, it redirected me to the method, and I changed the view
   back to IL)

Comment: You understand that many languages can generate a `.exe`, and moreover, many languages can generate the *exact same* managed CLR assembly, right?

Comment: If it is a "class project" it is one hell of a difficult one. There is no 100% way to do that.

Comment: @KirkWoll True but that doesn't mean I can't use tools to help identify the language that the exe was most likely written with.

Comment: @CriketerOnSO It is. I have one of those teachers that asks us nearly impossible questions and hopes one of us is smart enough to figure it out. I hope crowdsourcing will help me out.

Comment: Decompilers like DotPeek decompile into a specific language. If its a .NET assembly, the language could be any .NET supported language, from C++/CLI to VB, and they can all be decompiled into each other. There's not an easy way to tell. You can kind-of rule out VB if the VisualBasic namespace isn't included, but not always since you can include it from C# or C++... Its possible to even have a mixture of native  assembled code and CIL in one assembly.

Comment: @RonBeyer There are some subtle differences between code compiled from VB.NET and C#. For example the use of hidebysig

Comment: @RonBeyer I didn't find any references to visual basic. I had no clue that both C# and C++ can be used at the same time in the same exe.

Comment: @SILENT yes, they can, especially when you do assembly merging. This is used a lot when people want to hide code from decompiling, the software creates a native wrapper around the MSIL assembly to hide it from tools like DotPeek.

Comment: @xanatos, you can get both during assembly merging in the same assembly, but yes, typically c# code includes the hidebysig in MSIL where VB does not. I'm not sure how the C++/CLI handles it though, the EMCA standard isn't clear on when its used, only what it does.

Comment: How would you handle an executable (assembly) written in C#, C++, C and assembly?  Which language was it created in?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Depending on what compiler was used, there may be various hints in the binary - some compilers put a copyright message, some generate symbol names in a certain name. C# generates managed assemblies which have a very different binary structrure from unmanaged ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done some experiments by creating some empty console applications in Visual Studio.

C#:

There is nothing particular in a C# program. It is very "plain". There is no strange reference to other assemblies. An empty app references only mscorlib. The `Main` method is hidebysig.

VB.NET:

Even an empty Console App has a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`. There are tons of things defined in `(assemblynamespace).My` and in `(assemblynamespace).My.Resources` . The `Main` method is **not** hidebysig.

F#:

Even a nearly empty Consol App has a reference to `FSharp.Core`. The `Main` method is **not** hidebysig.

C++/CLI with /clr:

There are classes in the `<CppImplementationDetails>` and in the `<CrtImplementationDetails>` namespaces. A reference to kernel32.dll is shown in ILSPY. The start method is `internal unsafe static int mainCRTStartupStrArray(string[] arguments)`. It is not `hidebysig`.

C++/CLI with /pure:

There are classes in the `<CppImplementationDetails>` and in the `<CrtImplementationDetails>` namespaces. A reference to kernel32.dll is shown in ILSPY. The start method is `internal unsafe static int mainCRTStartupStrArray(string[] arguments)`. It is not `hidebysig`.

C++/CLI with /safe:

Methods outside classes are defined inside an `internal class <Module>`. The `main` (lowercase) method is **not** hidebysig.

ILAsm:

Not tested, but quite sure that anything that is pure IL code can be generated

Other languages:

You can often look at the referenced assemblies. Often languages that compile for .NET have some additional assemblies with special classes for them (like the VB.NET `Microsoft.VisualBasic`

-

Note that if the exe is "pure" IL Code there should be a

.corflags 0x00000001 // ILOnly

If it is mixed native + ILCode instead:

.corflags 0x00000000 // 0

I can see it by loading the exe in ILSPY, choosing it and selecting IL in the combo box in the toolbar. It is the last line

**At first I assumed its a C++ / CLI project but I also discovered a reference to System.Windows.Forms and methods that would decompile to C#.**

Using C++ / CLI or C# and using `System.Windows.Forms` are orthogonal. You can use any .NET language with `System.Windows.Forms`. The big difference is that with C++ / CLI you can put in the exe non-IL code plus IL code, while with C# you can only generate IL code.

Comment: These are the main differences I referred to in my answer - thank you for going through the excercise of listing them. +1

Comment: Can you generate C programs with GNU C and CLang and compare the executables?  I don't think these have any hints as to which language the executable was created from.  Also, no debug information allowed.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No, I don't have them. I think the first distinction should be if it is ILOnly or mixed code. Then if it is mixed code he could look at the referenced dlls, with http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Its mixed native + ILCode.

Comment: @xanatos How do you find out if the main method has hidebysig or not?

Comment: @silent with ilspy you select as the language il and it is in the signature. The **name** of the main method can be seen in the page of the assembly

Comment: @xanatos Thanks. I'm searching all the methods for a Main method.

Comment: @SILENT On ILSPY, if you look at the assembly with C# language selected, you should have a `Entry point:` comment, around the third/fourth line. Then you can look for the method name in View->Search->Member

Comment: @xanatos Awesome. It points to _WinMainCRTStartup and there is no hidebysig.

Comment: @xanatos You're a genius. It looks like it may be a C++/CLI with /safe since its entry point is <Module>._WinMainCRTStartup . Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: @SILENT If it is mixed then it is /clr

Comment: @xanatos Even though the Main method isn't mainCRTStartupStrArray ?

Comment: @SILENT Probably being a Winforms it has a different name

Answer (score 2):

Your question is hard to answer with certainty, but the Visual Studio VB.Net, C# and C++ compilers all output slightly different assemblies when they compile projects so you can have a reasonably accurate guess.

Some features (like pointers) are only available through C# or C++/CLI and other, special hidden types can differentiate between these two. In most cases, you should look at the the code decompiled into IL, not VB.Net or C# because certain attributes in IL may not be correctly (or at all) decompiled into a target language by a decompiler. In this case, ILDasm would probably be the best choice (even though its user interface is the least convenient to use) - it shows some extra information that other decompilers may hide.

Another useful tool for this kind of work is [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) - it shows the binary structure of PE executables.

Whatever your guess is, it may be off if the assembly has been merged from multiple different assemblies or if it has been obfuscated or otherwise transformed.

Frankly, this seems like a pretty pointless excercise, since even if you can tell what compiler generated the output, it doesn't give you much. Other vendors' compilers may generate yet different compiled outputs, so if your .exe has been output by a non-Microsoft compiler, that makes it even harder.

Comment: If I generate an EXE from FORTRAN, can you tell it was generated from a FORTRAN compiler or a C++ compiler?  Similarly with Pascal and SNOBOL.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't know the definitive answer to your question, but in general, yes, I've been able to do that for years. It may not work for every single version of every compiler but usually there are differences in output even in native code executables. We're not talking about an exact science here.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews "high level" languages normally have fixed dependancies (dll) that you can't remove. You use http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and look for them. Then you can look for error messages/strings contained in the exe. Normally from them you can see the copyrights of the compiler and deduce something.

Comment: @xanatos: Many "high level" languages have the capability of compiling into executables that don't use DLLs or Shared Libraries.  This project is much like [turning hamburger into a cow](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+hamburger+into+cow&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews There are only _very few_ tools that don't have telltale signs in their binary output. Usually when I can't identify the source of a binary it's not because of the lack of these signs but because I'm not familiar with the tool that generated the binary or because the binary was further transformed.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Identifying the source language of a binary has nothing to do with actually decompiling it into any particular source code. Your link is not relevant to this discussion.

Comment: @xxbbcc: I disagree.  An executable, binary image, is not required to put in any information about the source language(s) used in generation, into the executable.  So, given an executable with no source information, this is like trying to turn hamburger into a cow.  It could be turned into a cow, but what kind of a cow?  Or were other by-products inserted into the hamburger?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't understand what you're referring to. No one said that it's possible to _decompile_ a binary into source code in the general case. Just because tools are not required to put identifying marks into the binary, they still do (on purpose and / or as a conincidence) and that can be used to _identify the source language_. Just because one can tell that Pascal was used to write an executable one cannot revert the binary to source code.